# not able to download anything on software center

Tags: installation, software-center

i started with ubuntu just about 3-4 hours ago. I did only install it for some software-developement purposes (ruby, phyton, perl, etc.).

When i'm going to get any kind of applications over the ubuntu software center, i'm not able to install everything. The "Install"-item in the topmenu is always locked..i only receive the following sentence, when i'm going to get more information about a application:

'available from the "main" source' - Use This Source

Nothing happens after clicking on 'Use This Source'.

If u need any further information, please tell me.

Thanks in advance,
Maxi

Comment: can you add a screenshot to the question?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nathan said, but in case it doesn't work, this might work instead. I fixed it once by going to software-center, `edit > Software Sources`. Disabled everything, closed window (`sudo apt-get update` just to check there's nothing) and then re-enable everything but the source-code repositories.

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to do is to go to the Synaptic Package Manager, then at the top click Settings, then Repositories. See if you can enable and reload the packages from Synaptic then go back to the Ubuntu Software Center.
If you do not have Synaptic, type `sudo apt-get install synaptic` in the terminal.